# Why was this seemingly on-topic answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/7609/51

This answer was deleted without comment, and I didn't see an immediate reason why. As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with it: it answers the question, isn't spammy, doesn't contain bad information, and is reasonably helpful.

I can't vote to undelete because it was a mod-close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [moved to a comment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-should-i-properly-prepare-a-raised-bed-vegetable-garden/78#comment7921_78) on [winwaed's answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/78/26). It seemed to be a continuation of his thought, specifically his [comment](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-should-i-properly-prepare-a-raised-bed-vegetable-garden/78#comment79_78) on the answer, rather than a complete answer in and of itself.

Comment: oop, good catch @nial

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed that

Comment: @bstpierre no problem at all. Glad you asked :).